# Ajuda com While em c++

Tags: c++, while

Fiquei curioso com o seguinte código em c++.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    float n1,n2,n3,n4;
    int i = 1;
    char nomeAluno;
    
    printf("Digite seu nome: ");
    scanf("%s", &nomeAluno);
    while(i<5){
        printf("Digite sua %dº nota: ", i);
        scanf("%f", &n1);
        
        i++;
    }
    printf("%.1f \n", n1);
    printf("%.1f \n", n2);
    printf("%.1f \n", n3);
    printf("%.1f \n", n4);
    return 0;
}
```

Tenho a seguinte dúvida, eu não sei se é possível, mas se for como eu consigo fazer com que dentro do while a próxima digitação da nota caia dentro do n2? Porque dessa forma que eu fiz ele fica armazenando só no n1(Claro que por conta do loop).

Comment: A declaração `char nomeAluno;` define a variável que conterá **um** único caractere (neste caso o formato é %c) e não uma string. Para uma string, que em C é um array de caracteres com o caractere terminador '\0', use `char nomeAluno[40];` e na função scanf não coloque o &. Aliás em C++ você deveria utilizar a classe string. Quanto às notas você colocou a leitura dentro de um loop e portanto a cada nova leitura você sobrescreve o que foi lido na leitura anterior. Ou faça leituras separadas para cada uma das notas ou utilize um array de notas (`float nota[4];`).

Comment: Não me atentei a essa diferença entre usar %c e %s, sobre o & não sabia que era melhor usar um string. Vou estudar mais de qualquer forma e sou grato pelos conselhos. :)

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar vetores. Para declara-los, é simples, basta digitar a variável e logo em seguida entre chaves `[]` a quantidade de posições que vai receber a variável `float n[4]`, aqui eu declarei uma array do tipo float de 4 posições (lembrando que C++ os valores de um vetor iniciam com 0).

Um exemplo prático de como ficaria o seu código:

```
int i = 0;
float n[4];
while(i<4){
    printf("Digite sua %dº nota: ", i+1);
    scanf("%f", &n[i]);
    
    i++;
}
printf("%.1f \n", n[0]);
printf("%.1f \n", n[1]);
printf("%.1f \n", n[2]);
printf("%.1f \n", n[3]);
return 0;
}
```

> Observe que eu declaro int i = 0, e que no printf, eu adiciono i + 1 para imprimir da forma que tem que ser mostrada para o usuário, este valor alterará apenas na impressão, e não somará na variável i.

Para ver mais sobre, recomendo estes dois links:

http://linguagemc.com.br/vetores-ou-arrays-em-linguagem-c/

[https://www.inf.pucrs.br/~pinho/LaproI/Vetores/Vetores.htm](https://www.inf.pucrs.br/%7Epinho/LaproI/Vetores/Vetores.htm)

Comment: Muito obrigado, vou utilizar vetores então. E grato pelos links. :D

Comment: De nada amigo, teve uma errata, em `while()` eu coloquei `while(i<5)`, na verdade é `while(i<4)` e leia-se `enquanto i for menor que 4`, pois temos apenas 4 posições para serem preenchidas, e a variável `i` inicia com `0`, agora está correto. Lembrando que é perigoso em um programa dar valores a um vetor maior que ele mesmo, você está alterando a memória que pode estar sendo usada por outra instancia, variável, etc.